# ActionScript 3 Flash CS6 - Fade out audio

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, fadeout

I have this background music which plays on the menu. I want to make it fade out smoothly whenever the player selects the "start" button (`startBtn`). How do you do that?
Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.system.fscommand;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//Declare MUSIC Variables
var musicSelection:Sound;
var musicChannel:SoundChannel;
var musicTrack:String = "music/dearly_beloved.mp3";
var musicVolume:Number=0.2;
/*var isMuted = false;*/

loadMusic();
function loadMusic():void 
{
    //first stop old sound playing
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    musicSelection = new Sound();
    musicChannel = new SoundChannel();
    //create and load the required soun
    musicSelection.load(new URLRequest(musicTrack));
    //when loaded - play it
    musicSelection.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, musicLoaded);
}

function musicLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
    //finished with this listener
    musicSelection.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, musicLoaded);
    //play music
    playMusic();
}

function playMusic():void
{
    //play the random or selected music
    musicChannel = musicSelection.play();
    //setting the volume control property to the music channel
    musicChannel.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(musicVolume, 0);
    //but add this one to make repeats
    musicChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playAgain);
}

function playAgain(evt:Event):void
{
    // remove this listener and repeat
    musicChannel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playAgain);
    playMusic();
}
```

and this is the code for the second frame:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;

stop();

optionBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToOption)
function goToOption(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
}

startBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stopMusic);
function stopMusic(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    musicChannel.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(musicVolume, 0);
    while (musicVolume > 0)
    {
        musicVolume--;
    }
}

quitBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, closeGame);
function closeGame(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    fscommand("quit");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using while... will only decrease the music instantly - in one frame. What you need to do is to add ENTER_FRAME event, and inside it, you decrease the music. Something like this :

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoop);

var _oldTime:Number = 0;
private function onLoop(e:Event):void
{
   var resultTime:Number = getTimer() - oldTime;
   if(resultTime > 200 )
   {
      musicVolume -= 0.1;
      oldTime += resultTime;
      if(musicVolume <= 0) 
      {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onLoop);
      } 
   }
}
```

Depending on the speed you want, try different values for decreasing the volume, or when to decrease (result time > 200  -> 200ms)

Answer (score 0):

You could use TweenMax to tween out the volume:

http://www.greensock.com

[http://forums.greensock.com/topic/4753-volume-fade-outs/page_*hl*_volume](http://forums.greensock.com/topic/4753-volume-fade-outs/page__hl__volume)